# Can I steal power to power up new recessed lighting from a switch box that has a 2 pole switch?

Tags: wiring

I'm installing recessed lighting in my living room, and I had to run the new light wires down the wall to obtain a power source and the switch box for the power source is right at the stairs and the switch for the stair lights is a 2 pole with the connected/ matching switch at the top of the stairs. I have it all wired up but the 2pole switch that controls the stairs light also turns on the new recessed lights, but I have have a lytton Cassetta switch and this switch also works to control the recessed lights. How do I wire up so the single pole cassetta switch works separately from the stairs switch. Also I was thinking to open up the top of the stairs light switch box and install a cassette pico with to sync with a cassetta switch for the bottom of stairs but how do I wire it hot for the bottom of the stairs bc the pico switch just syncs and controls the bottom switch. on the 2 pole switch theres a red, white, blk, & ground. Thanks everyone!

Comment: When there are 3-way switches involved, which is the case for "top/bottom of stairs", it gets complicated. Basically, power to run *other* switches/lights is only available at one end or the other. **Unless** you take full advantage of smart switches, but then you sometimes get into neutral issues. **Please upload pictures of all the existing switches showing the wires, but do not disconnect any wires.**

Comment: When you say "2-pole switches", do you mean "3-way switches" such as allow you to control a light from 2 places?  A 2-pole switch is something completely different. It'd be like saying EV when you mean SUV :)

Comment: Since you've had everything open, it would behoove you to open up all the switches again and take some clear, focused pics of how you have the wiring now, showing both sides of all switches involved and the wiring in each box. Label the switches/wiring (either physically or digitally), then [edit] your post and upload the pics (the "sun & mountain" icon) so that we can see what you're talking about. Additionally, break your wall of text into a paragraph or 2 to make it easier for others to read - dividing by thought/concept is really helpful.

Comment: Yes, can you get us photos of the inside of the boxes involved please?